# Data signed on iOS can't be verified in Java

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, java-security, commoncrypto

I have some data that I'm signing on iOS with `SecKeyRawSign` using Elliptic Curve private key. However, verifying that data in Java using `Signature.verify()` returns `false`

The data is a random 64 bit integer, split into bytes like so

```
uint64_t nonce = (some 64 bit integer)
NSData *nonceData = [NSData dataWithBytes: &nonce length: sizeof(nonce)];
```

From that data I'm creating a SHA256 digest

```
int digestLength = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
uint8_t *digest = malloc(digestLength);
CC_SHA256(nonceData.bytes, (CC_LONG)nonceData.length, digest);
NSData *digestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:digestLength];
```

and then signing it with private key

```
size_t signedBufferSize = kMaxCipherBufferSize;
uint8_t *signedBuffer = malloc(kMaxCipherBufferSize);

OSStatus status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKeyRef,
                                kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256,
                                (const uint8_t *)digestData.bytes,
                                digestData.length,
                                &signedBuffer[0],
                                &signedBufferSize);

NSData *signedData = nil;
if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    signedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:signedBuffer length:signedBufferSize];
}
```

Everything appears to work fine.

Then, in Java server, I'm trying to verify that signed data

```
PublicKey publicKey = (a public key sent from iOS, X509 encoded)

Long nonce = (64 bit integer sent from iOS)
String signedNonce = (base64 encoded signed data)

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
buffer.putLong(nonce);
byte[] nonceBytes = buffer.array();
byte[] signedNonceBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedNonce.getBytes());

Signature signer = Signature.getInstance( "SHA256withECDSA" );
signer.initVerify( publicKey );
signer.update( nonceBytes );
Boolean isVerified = signer.verify( signedNonceBytes );
```

At this point, `signer.verify()` returns `false`

I also tried to sign plain data, instead of SHA256 digest, but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing? Am I signing the data correctly? Am I using correct padding? Is there something else to be done with data to be able to verify it with `SHA256withECDSA` algorithm?

Comment: Can you encrypt the same Nonce in Java with same algo and see if encrypted versions are coming different? So basically you encrypt at both ends and see if the encrypted data is same or not

Comment: I would recommend to check that the ObjC side is correct: (1) is the size of the generated signature the expected size? and (2) can you verify the signature in ObjC code? And a wild guess: may this be an endianness problem? I.e `[NSData dataWithBytes: &nonce...` accesses the actual raw memory, while the Java side might see the nonce in a more generic "network" endianness. Therefore try whether a nonce of 0 works.

Comment: One of the errors is byte ordering. iOS is little endian. The way you create `nonceData`, this order is retained. However on the Java side, `ByteBuffer` defaults to big endian. So you need to add: `buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);`

Comment: @Codo this was it. Please write is as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ok, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte ordering does not match:

- iOS is *little endian*. The way you create `nonceData`, this order is retained.
- On the Java side, `ByteBuffer` defaults to *big endian*, independent of the underlying operating system / hardware.

So you need to change the byte order:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buffer.putLong(nonce);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a java guy, so I can't say anything about the iOS side, but a quick check of the java side can be done using the commented assumptions:

```
// Generate a new random EC keypair for testing
KeyPair keys = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC").generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keys.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keys.getPublic();

// Generate a Random nonce to test with
byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[8]; // (some 64 bit integer)
new Random(System.nanoTime()).nextBytes(nonceBytes);

// sign     
Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
sign.initSign(privateKey);
sign.update(nonceBytes);
byte[] signature = sign.sign();

//verify
Signature verify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
verify.initVerify(publicKey);
verify.update(nonceBytes);
Boolean isVerified = verify.verify(signature);

// print results
System.out.println("nonce used  ::" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonceBytes));
System.out.println("Signed nonce ::" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature));
System.out.println("nonce used ::" + isVerified);
```

As you'd expect returns, the code above will always return that the signature is verified. Check your assumptions are accurate and validate the keys being used are correct on *both* sides.

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you to use some Crypto Library which is available for both iOS and JAVA sides (f.e.:https://github.com/VirgilSecurity/virgil-crypto). This will ensure that the algorithm and block types (etc.) are the same in both cases and you won't need to worry about it anymore. I believe you will finds many crypto libraries on a GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

In getBytes() you could specify the encoding technique using java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets. and do the same with the decoder.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html

Comment: I tried it, if not specified it defaults to UTF-8, which is the encoding I use in iOS

Comment: Try this one then. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html

Comment: Or like CoDo suggested you could use getBytes( StandardCharacters.UTF_16LE)